# What is the best way to assign data into header.blade in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to create account selection dropdown in header. On the basis of account,data will load for particular account.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-pass-variables-to-master-template

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/using-blade-echo-to-display-a-page-title?page=0

Comment: Thanks @Tom but if i hit the urls directly will it work? in my case actually the different routes have been called.

Comment: @murtuzahussain i guess in provided link ,data is assigned from controller i want to assign before any controller called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#sharing-data-with-all-views to share data for all your views as it is header (I suppose that header exists in all your views)

Comment: Thanks.Currently i have done using this approach but i don't know why view loads before service providers are called when i hit ulrs directly.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this over a middleware :)

So php artisan make:middleware YourMiddleWare.

Then in handle write your logic and call view share

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $foo = 'bar';

    View::share(["foo" => $foo]);

    return $next($request);
}
```

And then in your Middleware/Kernel.php:

```
protected $middleware = [
    YourMiddleWare::class,
];
```

Comment: should i have to call the middleware from every controller?

Comment: no you just register it in the kernel and it works automatically

Comment: has my answer helped you and is it correct? :) then please mark it as correct answer :)

Comment: I am not able to upvote as i am new user yet to get privilege.

Comment: but you should can mark an answer as correct :) there should be a check you can click :)

Comment: I still don't know which is the correct answer, i will surely mark correct if it works.Thanks

Comment: ok cool :) The advantage of the middleware though is, that it gets called before every request. So when a request is made before accessing a controller the middleware is called. I supposed that was what you wanted :)

Comment: although we are using this middleware as global but my auth middleware is in routeMiddleware list so i am not able to use Auth::user object in MyMiddleware.
And I don't want headache to add MyMiddleware in each controller.

`
protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddleware::class,
    ];

 protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    ];

`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the view composers in laravel to assign a data to a view each time it is rendered. More details here: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#view-composers